# For/if/else loop has unexpected identifier

Tags: loops, if-statement, for-loop

```
function hitPlayer()
{
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++);
    {
        if i==0;
        {
            turnCard('hit5'};
        }
        else if i==1;
        {
            turnCard('hit6');
        }
        else if i==2;
        {
            turnCard('hit7');
        }
        else;
        {
            turnCard('hit8');
        }
    }
}
```

all variables and other functions work fine. this is for a blackjack game
also how to i get the loop to pause after i++ without resetting "i"

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *pause*, but your sintax looks not quite alright, actually.

Comment: As @AndreCalil points out, you don't want the semicolon on the line with `for`. But I'd go a little further. This isn't how loops are supposed to work. You should learn a little more about how to abstract your code and not repeat yourself, and then revisit this. (I recommend Bruce Eckel's _Thinking in Java_ book.)

Comment: I don't know what language this is, but you have way too many `;`.

Comment: what do you mean by "pausing" the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about every angle-bracket language I know follows the following conventions:

- The condition of an `if` statement normally goes in parenthesis
- You shouldn't have a curly brace at the end of `turnCard('hit5'};`
- You shouldn't have a `;` at the end of your if-statements(or your `for` statement)
- Some languages allow you to use single-quotes like that for strings(javascript will), but some languages don't allow that.  Almost all of them allow double-quotes.  Without knowing the language, I'd suggest using double quotes just to be safe

  ```
  if (i==0)
  {
      turnCard("hit5");
  }
  ```

Comment: Theoretically the OP could be using some language where the original syntax is (almost) correct, but this is most likely the right answer.

Comment: @Juhana  I can't imagine a language that would accept the curly brace at the end of the function call and the semicolon immediately after the if statement